# Cassandra Data Modelling issue

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, data-modeling, datastax

Could you please help me in modeling my table below.I'm stuck here. My Partition key is `agent_id` and clustering column is `rowid`. Each agent can have a minimum of 1000 rows to 10M depends on how busy the agent. I'm facing large partition issue for my busy agents.

I'm using SizeTieredCompaction here.. The table has Writes/Reads (70/30 ratio) and have deletes also in the table by `agent_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS XXX (
 agent_id UUID,
 row_id BIGINT,
 col_a TEXT,
 col_b TEXT,
 col_c TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY (agent_id,row_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes up many times when modeling in C*.

1. If any of the columns (`col_a`, `col_b`, etc) has something to do with time, and you know how many (approximately) rows per agent you are going to insert every day, I would strongly recommend the `year-month-day` as a partition key (if a day is enough, if not, go to hour or minute).
2. You can do some kind of hashing on the agent_id + row_id modulo 1M (for example). That hash can be the partition key, and you do that hashing in the application before inserting and or retrieving. That way you know that if your estimated amount of rows is 10M, your partitions are going to have size 10.